# MySQL rejects valid password via Command line on Windows

Tags: mysql

After successfully creating new users 'u1' and 'u2' in `mysql.user` table and setting their passwords to `pass` and `PASSWORD('pass')` respectively, I am unable to log in as either user.  Please review the commands below and help me figure out what I'm missing.  Note that each concealed password is just the string "pass"
[image]

Why is access denied? Note that I was the root user (with all privileges) when I created the users u1 and u2

Comment: No way yo know if you are mistyping something, or an invisible character snuck in in the code, or...

Comment: wow stumping me. check this out: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/problems-connecting.html

Comment: you directly modified the user tables, which is a bad idea. just because a record exists in the user table doesn't mean they can access the db. you have to `GRANT` **USAGE** as well...

Comment: @Drew - oh yeah! you altered the table and didn't create the user. OP What you want to do is login as root, then run Drew's commands

Comment: I feel stupid; the 2nd attempt: `mysql -u 'u2' -p` is working now with password `pass`.  I am almost positive it wasn't working before. Now I'm wondering whether I'm crazy.  What could explain the change? Between my post and now, I logged out, logged in as the root user, and executed `flush privileges`, `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'`, `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'u1'`

Comment: Patrick it is a one-way hash for a reason. So basically, no.

Comment: Drew I don't mean to undo the hash. I mean is there a login option that shows the characters as you're typing them.

Comment: sure, like `mysql -uu3 -ppass`, or `mysql -uu4 -p` ... note I am not putting any spaces after -u and -p basically to avoid the pesky error that wastes hours sometimes

Comment: oooops, sorry Patrick, with the -p option with nothing after it, NO, the password is not seen upon being prompted for it, perhaps asterisks are seen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE USER 'u3'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';

CREATE USER 'u4'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
```

A good question from the OP prompted this: The two users just created above have basically **no privileges** to the server yet, except to login and sit there. They are awaiting the Grant command to allow them various access rights to certain databases.

Then try them. There is a reason the **create user** command was created.

After that you deal with grants to particular databases. And revisit the **host** issue.

But this is just a test.

Then to login from o/s command line, it is `mysql -uu3 -p` and ENTER. You will then be prompted for password. It is highly recommended not to login as root unless you know you are doing maintenance. Also, do not *bake* the password into a script file such as `mysql -uu3 -ppass` as your file could be poached and your password too. Note, no space after -u and -p in my example.

And yes, with the -p switch, when you are prompted for password, it is **not** visible.

Create User command from the [Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-user.html).

Drop User command from the [Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/drop-user.html).

Grant command from the [Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html). Be very careful not to use wildcards and `WITH GRANT OPTION` with the Grant command. You need to be careful to grant the minimal rights for users necessary for them, versus being lazy and applying wildcards.

Comment: This worked. I'm just learning this so did not now about `CREATE USER`.  Is there a matching command to properly remove a user from `mysql.user` table?  I also learned from your link that `CREATE USER` grants the `USAGE` privilege, but it's not clear what that entails.  Is it the same as privilege `SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE`?

Comment: yes sir, refresh Answer, it is there

Comment: the usage privilege is a 'I am a blind user so far' privilege. **The USAGE privilege specifier stands for “no privileges.”** ... as seen here from Manual [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_usage)

Comment: so **u3** and **u4** users from the top of my Answer are basically able to login, and just sit there, doing nothing, except maybe `select now();`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried restarting the server before connecting? From [The MySQL Documentation:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privilege-changes.html)

> If you modify the grant tables directly using statements such as INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE, your changes have no effect on privilege checking until you either restart the server or tell it to reload the tables. If you change the grant tables directly but forget to reload them, your changes have no effect until you restart the server. This may leave you wondering why your changes do not seem to make any difference!

Comment: While messing around after my OP, one of the commands I executed as `root` was `flush privileges`.  At the time, the server returned `Query OK, 0 rows affected` so I didn't think anything of it. Do you think that command could explain why logging in as user `u2` with password `pass` eventually started to work?